# Loaded procedure executed twice for TFrame's descendant

Tags: delphi, components, tframe

I've registered as component a `TFrame`'s descendant class and I've noticed that the `Loaded` procedure is executed twice:

**Runtime:**

```
  TMyFrame = class(TFrame)
  private
  protected
    procedure Loaded(); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
  end;

constructor TMyFrame.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  ShowMessage('Before TMyFrame.Create');
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  ShowMessage('After TMyFrame.Create');
end;

procedure TMyFrame.Loaded();
begin
  ShowMessage('Before TMyFrame.Loaded');
  inherited;
  ShowMessage('After TMyFrame.Loaded');
end;
```

**Designtime:**

```
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TMyFrame]);
end;
```

**Output:**

At runtime, on creating a form in which there is a `TMyFrame` component.

> Before TMyFrame.Create
>
> Before TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Create
>
> Before TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Loaded

At designtime, on adding a `TMyFrame` to a form:

> Before TMyFrame.Create
>
> Before TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Create

At designtime, opening a form in which there is a `TMyFrame` component:

> Before TMyFrame.Create
>
> Before TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Create
>
> Before TMyFrame.Loaded
>
> After TMyFrame.Loaded

Why the `Loaded` procedure is executed twice? How to avoid this?

Comment: If you compile with Debug DCUs you can set a breakpoint and see the callstack.

Comment: *When* do you see these messages? In the IDE? or at Run Time? If in the IDE you don't really care so surround your messages with a test for componentstate = csDesigning.

Comment: @Dsm: "After adding a TMyFrame to a form, at runtime,".

Comment: @Rudy - Thanks -yes I shouldn't speed-read!

Comment: @Dsm: It also happens on designtime, I have updated the question by reporting all the output messages.

Comment: Could maybe check ComponentState for csLoading to see if it has finished such. If you're interested in construction instead of loading could maybe override AfterConstruction method (do call inherited there though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is as-designed.

[Loaded](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Loaded)

> Loaded may be called multiple times on inherited forms. It is called
>   every time a level of inheritance is streamed in. Do not allocate
>   memory in an overridden Loaded method without first checking that the
>   memory has not been allocated in a previous call.

Comment: Do you know a way to distinguish the last execution? (In paritcular, I would like to use some variables that are initialized in the constructor)

Comment: No. Probably the safest thing would be moving your code from `Loaded` to `AfterConstruction`.