# How to store a form's design settings?

Tags: delphi

In a `TForm` descendant with several levels of inheritance.

```
... TForm -> TForm1 -> TForm2 -> TForm3
```

Each level, from the DFM designer, modifies the form's `Caption` (i.e: 'A' for `TForm1`, 'B' for `TForm2` and 'C' for `TForm3`).

At runtime, for a `TForm3` form, I would like to save the initial `Caption`'s value ('C') in a private form's field (i.e: `FInitialCaption : string`).
I thought to use the [`Loaded`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Loaded) procedure but the documentation states:

> **Warning: Loaded** may be called multiple times on inherited forms. It is called every time a level of inheritance is streamed in. Do not
>   allocate memory in an overridden **Loaded** method without first
>   checking that the memory has not been allocated in a previous call.

In this example case, I'm sure it will not cause any appreciable problem, but I'm wondering which is the right place for reacting to the DFM settings once for all, avoiding useless code execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture this in an overridden constructor, or an `OnCreate` event handler.

Personally I would use a constructor for this since I see little point to the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events.

Comment: In past, I had some problems because the [`Loaded` was excuted after the constructor for a `TFrame` descendant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44515417/4528159). Can't the same thing happen with `TForm` descendants?

Comment: @Fabrizio The code in an overridden form constructor executes after the properties have been streamed from the dfm file